# Pandas MultiIndex: Selecting a column knowing only the second index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm working with the following DataFrame:

```
   age  height  weight  shoe_size
0  8.0     6.0     2.0        1.0
1  8.0     NaN     2.0        1.0
2  6.0     1.0     4.0        NaN
3  5.0     1.0     NaN        0.0
4  5.0     NaN     1.0        NaN
5  3.0     0.0     1.0        0.0
```

I added another header to the df in this way:

```
zipped = list(zip(df.columns, ["RHS", "height", "weight", "shoe_size"]))

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(zipped)
```

So this is the new DataFrame:

```
   age height weight shoe_size
   RHS height weight shoe_size
0  8.0    6.0    2.0       1.0
1  8.0    NaN    2.0       1.0
2  6.0    1.0    4.0       NaN
3  5.0    1.0    NaN       0.0
4  5.0    NaN    1.0       NaN
5  3.0    0.0    1.0       0.0
```

Now I know how to select the first column, by using the corresponding tuple `("age", "RHS")`:

```
df[("age", "RHS")]
```

but I was wondering about how to do this by using only the second index "RHS".
Ideally something like:

```
df[(any, "RHS")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `slice(None)` as the first argument to `.loc`, provided you sort your columns first using `df.sort_index`:

```
In [325]: df.sort_index(1).loc[:, (slice(None), 'RHS')]
Out[325]: 
   age
   RHS
0  8.0
1  8.0
2  6.0
3  5.0
4  5.0
5  3.0
```

You can also use `pd.IndexSlice` with `df.loc`:

```
In [332]: idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [333]: df.sort_index(1).loc[:, idx[:, 'RHS']]
Out[333]: 
   age
   RHS
0  8.0
1  8.0
2  6.0
3  5.0
4  5.0
5  3.0
```

With the slicer, you don't need to explicitly pass `slice(None)` because `IndexSlice` does that for you.

---

If you don't sort your columns, you get:

```
UnsortedIndexError: 'MultiIndex Slicing requires the index to be fully lexsorted tuple len (2), lexsort depth (0)'
```

If you have multiple `RHS` columns in the second level, *all* those columns are returned.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `get_level_values`

```
In [700]: df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1) == 'RHS']
Out[700]:
   age
   RHS
0  8.0
1  8.0
2  6.0
3  5.0
4  5.0
5  3.0
```